# Как создать языковой дамп для ингушского языка для клавиатуры AOSP?

Tags: java, android

Нужно создать клавиатуру на ингушском языке в приложение под андроид, для этого нужно найти дамп что бы создать словарь для клавиатуры AOSP, но в открытом доступе найти не удалось. Подскажите как это можно сделать есть готовый список слов в текстовом файле? Нашел исходники с разными языками, но ингушского там нет https://github.com/hermitdave/FrequencyWords

Подскажите что означают цифры возле каждого слова?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так в вашей ссылке есть объяснение — `numer_of_occurences_in_corpus`

Comment: и что это значит?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C